Is dividing an integer with value 0x80000000 an UB?
Here is the code
printf("%d", 0x80000000 / 10).
It prints a correct value with respect to its absolute value, but forgets to put a minus sign. Let's check if the original integer (signed) is negative.
printf("%d", 0x80000000) is negative indeed.
However, if I wrap the literal inside a value of type integer, the division retains the sign, which is the desired behavior. Explicitly casting to int the result of division also works.
I am using clang version 18.1.5

"... 0x80000000) is negative indeed." 0x80000000 is not negative, but it's value is probably outside of the range of an int on your system.

Note that MSVC has #define INT_MIN (-2147483647 - 1).

Note: aside from 10 implicitly converting to unsigned, there is no implicit type changes here.

Possible dupe: Why is 0 < -0x80000000?

0x80000000 is not an int*1.
0x80000000 is a positive unsigned constant.  So 0x80000000 / 10 is also not negative.  With an unsigned divided by an int (the 10), the int is converted to an unsigned and the quotient is also unsigned.
printf("%d", 0x80000000 / 10) and printf("%d", 0x80000000) are problems as they attempt to print an unsigned with "%d".  Use "%u" or "%x". *2

*1 assuming an int is 32-bit or less - which is very common.
*2 assuming an int is 32-bit.

Is there any logic behind such a behavior? Is it that bit twiddling is only usually done with unsigned integers?

@ArtyomGevorgyan Nothing special.  0x80000000 is a hexadecimal constant with the type of unsigned and decimal value of 2,147,483,648.  Why are you printing an unsigned with "%d" and not "%u" or "%x"?

Ah, it makes sense now. It also fits inside the class of unsigned integers.
